# Should I name the username field in my user table "name" or "username"?

Tags: mysql, naming

If I name it username then I would have to write user_username when referring to my field when I can just write user_name if it's named "name".  On the other hand, username sounds more appropriate than name.

Can someone help me make a decision?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call it `username`.

The field `name` (or `user_name` if you are prefixing all fields with the table name) is ambiguous because it might be their *real* name, which is usually different from their username.

Answer (score 0):

username, it's more specific and won't get mixed up with proper human names.

Here's a tip: while you're there, it's a good idea to decide on the proper name columns early - first_name and last_name or surname and given_name or whatever.  It doesn't really matter, but it's a right pain when tables are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

But you can also try `nickname`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is `login`